# internal energy of an ideal gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, gas

consider one mole of an ideal gas whose pressure changes with volume as P=(alpha)V . if it is expanded such that its volume increased to m times , find change in internal energy , heat capacity of the gas ?

Comment: Hi Saurav, you unfortunately don't show any research at all, or your own attempts to solve this question. If you do that, someone might give you a hint. I would strongly recommend hyperphysics.com, and a read of this site's homework policy. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Hi Saurav and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).